# node-oracledb package does not install on Redhat VM

Tags: node.js, redhat, node-oracledb

Good day geeks

I have been trying to run "npm install" on my node.js application which was developed on a windows machine and deployed on a Linux VM. The application interfaces with an Oracle DB. All modules do get installed except for the oracledb package. This is the error i am getting. 
[image]

node version: 8.11.3,

npm version: 5.6.0,

Linux version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

Note: All proxy and firewall settings have been opened

Anything i might have missed?

Comment: Are you running 'npm install -g'?  Somehow the user that is running the install is not able to create the required directory.  The install script called at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/v2.3.0/package/package.json#L37 seems to be failing at http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.autocommit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM network was blocking installations from the oracle Db repository

Comment: I'd also recommend using node-oracledb 3.1, which installs only from npmjs.com and doesn't have the internally executed, post-install step that downloaded a binary from GitHub as performed by older versions.

Answer (score 0):

The node-oracledb driver depends on some lower level C libraries, so you'll need to install those for things to work. See the [installation quick start](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#quickstart) (third bullet) for a high-level overview. That page also includes detailed instructions for various architectures.